# Deleting odd rows in a tree dynamically

Tags: python, recursion, tree, dynamic-programming

So I've been reviewing some old homework assignments, and one assignment we had was to use recursion to delete the odd rows of a tree (does not include the root). To help you visualize, here's an image of the initial tree:

[image: Tree]

So after the deleting method has been called, [bcd] would be gone, and [hi] would be gone. Here is my code for it recursively.

```
def deleteOddRows(self):
    oddRemoval = [] #Generate list with odd rows removed
    for child in self.getChildren(): #Children of the root
        for childChildren in child.getChildren(): #Grandchildren
            oddRemoval.append(childChildren) #Puts into list
            childChildren.deleteOddRows() 
    self.children = oddRemoval
```

I've gone back to this problem now and have tried solving it using dynamic programming, but I can't seem to wrap my head around a solution that would get me the result I'm looking for. If anyone can help point me in the right direction, that would be a great help. Thanks!

Comment: What is the meaning/point of using dynamic programming for this task ?

Comment: Its hard to tell without seeing how you implemented the tree class ...\